# google maps can't move the map correctly

Tags: html, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This is a jfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/w8NRr/

The problem is that when I try to move the map(please look at it in), the map moves and then go back automatically to its place, and the map is not fit to the space,

I don't have a css for map except the width and heigh

can u help please?

the map is on the button last `Next` in jfiddle

#### Edit

The code for map is so simple, if you don't know it kindly tell me to tell you it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove script:

```
            <script>
            function initialize() {
                var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
                var map_options = {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
                    zoom: 8,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                }
                var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options);
            }
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        </script>
```

**Under**

```
$(".next").click(function () {
```

**add**

```
if ($('fieldset').index($(this).parents('fieldset'))==2){
      var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
      var map_options = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }
      var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options);
}
```

working example : http://jsfiddle.net/w8NRr/2/

Comment: why did you make `==2` please?

Comment: That solved it just for once, I mean when you reach the last one and click previous and then next again, the problem will be fired again

Comment: the index of last fieldset. if you reach last you can't go previous, i see only submit button if you add prev button that's a NEW problem :)

Comment: the index is 3 not 2 right? and why the problem appears again if i click previous then next on the last one?

Comment: please why the problem is happens in the first place? what wrong did I do?

Comment: +1 for your efforts with me but please tell me what the solution

Comment: the code should be run only once, when you show the fieldset.

Comment: so why it stoped working when i click previous then next please?

Comment: change with that `var map;
$(".next").click(function () {
    if (($('fieldset').index($(this).parents('fieldset'))==2) && !(map) ){
      var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
      var map_options = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }
       map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options);
    }` [http://jsfiddle.net/w8NRr/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/w8NRr/4/)

Comment: now after your edit, when I click on the first `Next` nothing happens

Comment: and there is an error on the console `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier `

Comment: in the link you just added a var map outside the if? nothing more please?

Comment: Yes, and `if (($('fieldset').index($(this).parents('fieldset'))==2) && !(map)` and at the end of if `map =..` not `var map=..`